# Connecting R to Oracle using ODBC: How can I install driver of ODBC in Windows 64 bit?

Tags: r, windows, oracle, odbc, 64-bit

I am trying to connect R (64-bit) to Oracle using library RODBC.

I got to connect using R 32 bit, using the ODBC for Oracle driver for 32 bits, but this doesn't let me use all RAM (16gb).

I got this error: "ERROR: state IM014, code 0, message [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 
Manager] The specified DSN contains an architecture mismatch between the 
Driver and Application "

For what I've read, it seems that I need to install the ODBC driver for Oracle in 64 bits, so then I can make another DSN connection and then connect to the database in R 64-bit.

How can I install this driver?

Comment: In order to install both 32 bit and 64 bit Oracle Client on the same machine, have a look at this instruction: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24104210/badimageformatexception-this-will-occur-when-running-in-64-bit-mode-with-the-32#24120100 otherwise only one of your ODBC driver will work.

Answer (score 0):

If your problem is the Oracle driver you can find it on the Oracle website.It is indeed a good idea to match your R and data provider architecture.

Take a look at this page : [Oracle 64bit Drivers](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/database/windows/downloads/index-090165.html)

Get the corresponding install for your OS and give us feedback!
Cheers!